# Handling geoExt popup when one or more layer fails to load

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, geoext

GeoExt info Popup is very easy to use but when one or more layer is missing or fails to load 
[Avoiding Pink Tyles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20893/how-to-avoid-pink-tiles-when-db-view-table-is-empty). The popup is not filled with the values. While I can see that request is sent to the server and response is there but popup is blank. Is there any way to handle this condition without building custom component?

```js
OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadErrorColor = 1;
            OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadErrorColor = "transparent";  
            OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadError = function(){
                 this.src = "/img/blank.gif";
            };

controls.push(new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({              
                autoActivate: true,
                infoFormat: "application/vnd.ogc.gml",
                maxFeatures: 3,
                eventListeners: {
                    "getfeatureinfo": function(e) {                       
                        var items = [];
                        Ext.each(e.features, function(feature) {
                            items.push({
                                xtype: "propertygrid",
                                title: feature.fid,
                                source: feature.attributes
                            });
                        });

                        new GeoExt.Popup({
                            title: "Info",
                            width: 200,
                            height: 200,
                            layout: "accordion",
                            map: app.mapPanel,
                            location: e.xy,
                            maximizable: true,
                            collapsible: true,
                            items: items 
                        }).show();                      

                    }
                }
            }));
```

Comment: sample code please.

Comment: @CaptDragon Edited the question

Answer (score 2):

Try placing a condition to check to see if there are results first. `if (e.features.length > 0){`

like:

```js
"getfeatureinfo": function(e) {  
    if (e.features.length > 0){ //<-- add this if statement
        var items = [];
        Ext.each(e.features, function(feature) {
        ...
        });

        new GeoExt.Popup({
        ...
        }).show();                      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem isn't with the popup but with the get feature info request.
You need to control if the request is made right, if so show the popup and if there was any error not show the popup or show a message error.

Comment: the firebug doesn't show any error. There is get request for all layers including layer that is not loaded.